# Jquery Plugin refresh Variable

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have a working version of a textarea maxlength here: http://jsfiddle.net/73r8G/
I am attempting to convert this into a Jquery plugin. I need to refer to the updated content of the textarea box after line 120 but I not sure how to. My goal is to replace the ('.user_text') and ('.user_text_remaining') from my code.

My code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>Textarea Limits</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {




    (function($){ 
    $('.user_text').val('');    
    $.fn.truncate = function(options) {  
    var defaults = {  
        limit: 140
    };  
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

               return this.each(function() {  
               var options_limit = options.limit;
                //alert(options_limit);
               obj= $(this); 

               var content = obj.html();

                var fieldSelection = {
                    getSelection: function () {
                        var e = (this.jquery) ? this[0] : this;
                        return ( /* mozilla / dom 3.0 */ ('selectionStart' in e &&
                        function () {
                            var l = e.selectionEnd - e.selectionStart;
                            return {
                                start: e.selectionStart,
                                end: e.selectionEnd,
                                length: l,
                                text: e.value.substr(e.selectionStart, l)
                            };
                        }) || /* exploder */ (document.selection &&
                        function () {
                            e.focus();
                            var r = document.selection.createRange();
                            if (r === null) {
                                return {
                                    start: 0,
                                    end: e.value.length,
                                    length: 0
                                }
                            }
                            var re = e.createTextRange();
                            var rc = re.duplicate();
                            re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
                            rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
                            return {
                                start: rc.text.length,
                                end: rc.text.length + r.text.length,
                                length: r.text.length,
                                text: r.text
                            };
                        }) || /* browser not supported */
                        function () {
                            return null;
                        })();
                    }
                };
                jQuery.each(fieldSelection, function (i) {
                    jQuery.fn[i] = this;
                });


            function textAreaLength(options_limit, content) {
                var user_text_count = $('.user_text').val().length;
                if (options_limit - user_text_count <= 1) {
                    var determineCharacters = "character";
                } else {
                    determineCharacters = "characters";
                }
                $('.user_text_remaining').html(options_limit - user_text_count + " " + determineCharacters + " left");
            }

            function textCleanup(content) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (content.length > options_limit) {
                        trimmed = content.substr(0, options_limit);
                        $(this).val(trimmed);
                    }
                }, 10);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    textAreaLength(options_limit, content)
                }, 20);
            }

            var keys = [],
                counter17 = 0,
                presence = 0;
            function printKeys() {
                var html = '';
                var keycount = 0;
                for (var i in keys) {
                    keycount += 1;
                    //counter17 indicates the ctrl key
                    if (i == 17) counter17 += 1;
                    //presence indicates certain key presses; presence = 2 indicates ctrl; presence = 3 indicates ctrl and v
                    if (counter17 >= 1) {
                        presence = 2;
                        if (i == 86 || i == 118) {
                            presence = 3;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return presence;
            }

            //Keypress is used for Opera; ok for Firefox too        
            $(this).bind("keypress keydown", function (event) {     
                /*
                    want to refer to updated content in the textarea
                */
                if ($(this).getSelection().text == "" && $(this).val().length >= options_limit) {
                    //textarea is full; no more ctrl v
                    if ((event.which === 86 || event.which == 118) && event.ctrlKey) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    } else {
                        //preserve some keys after textarea is full; f5, arrows, backspace
                        if (event.which == 116 || event.which == 0 || event.which == 33 || event.which == 34 || event.which == 35 || event.which == 36 || event.which == 37 || event.which == 38 || event.which == 39 || event.which == 40 || event.which == 8) {
                            event
                        } else {
                            //single key presses are forbidden when textarea is full
                            if ((event.ctrlKey) == false) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                textCleanup(content); 
            }).keyup(function (e) {
                position = 2;
                delete keys[e.which];
            });

            //For IE and Chrome
            $(this).on('paste', function (event) {
                if ($(this).getSelection().text == "" && $(this).val().length >= options_limit) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }                
                textCleanup(content); 
            });


            }); 
        };             

    })(jQuery);     

        $('.user_text').truncate( {  
  limit: 150
 });    
        });
    </script>   
        <form name="myform" action="#">
            <textarea class="user_text" name="limitedtextarea" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
        </form>
        <p class="user_text_remaining">150 characters left</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. Learned how to use the $(this) variable properly. jquery plugin at http://jsfiddle.net/cdPzv/